# symfony login using database, no database queries performed

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have made login, repository for custom databasequery and it's working otherwise but there is no database queries made. Using Symfony 3

in firewall under providers:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    database:
        entity:
          class: AppBundle:Customer
          property: customer_email
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt
      cost: 20

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login_firewall:
        pattern: ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        # activate different ways to authenticate
        provider: database

        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            target_path_parameter: /dashboard
            always_use_default_target_path: true

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

        logout:
            path: /logout
access_control:

    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]
```

repository with query:

```
<?php

      # src/AppBundle/Entity/CustomerRepository.php
      namespace AppBundle\Entity;

      use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
      use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
      use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
      use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

      class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
      {
        public function loadUserByUsername($email)
        {
          $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.customer_email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email', $email)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

            if(null === $user)
            {
              $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active user AppBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $email
              );
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
              print_r('eac');
            }

            return $user;
        }
      }
```

However, still debugger says no queries performed, it will throw error with invalid login details thought.

Comment: Double check your security.yml file: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#configure-security-to-load-from-your-entity.  Are you sure no queries are being executed?  It looks like your user name is actually the email.  Might need to set the property.  But no queries at all suggests a security.yml config issue.

Comment: If u can trust symfony profiler, it says `Database Connections: doctrine.dal.default_connection`, top of that under Queries: `No database queries were performed.` If I add property: to security, like email there is no change, no queries performed

Comment: Update your question with the firewall portion of security.yml down to the provider line.  I think you have an error someplace.  And the property should probably be customer_email.  And make sure you clear the cache though it should be cleared automatically in development mode.

Comment: Code has been updated and I started to investigate               manager_name: in security.yml, and the meaning of it. AFAIK its entity manager but didn't accept Customer as one

Comment: Unless you have multiple entity managers defined then manager_name can be left to the default.  Still not seeing the firewall section in your question.

Comment: On my system, I have provider under form_login.  Might try moving it down.  I forget why I had it there instead of where you have it.  Been copy/pasting for some time now.

Comment: I moved it under form_login but still no luck or new error(s). In profiler: `Queries

No database queries were performed.
` However, if I typo provider, I will get error so it should work.

Comment: You need to change the encoder class name to your user entity. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#configure-security-to-load-from-your-entity. Not sure if that will impact the queries though.

Comment: I changed it to AppBundle:Customer but no luck... does security controller added to question help ?

Comment: I'm just guessing now.  I'm sure it's a simple config issue.  If your code is checked into a github repo I can take a look.  Otherwise, when I get stuck like this, I'll bring down a fresh S3 project and then just work my way through the configuration one step at a time.

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting frustrated :( I did exactly, I mean I typed, even copy pasted from symfony docs those all files and still no database queries performed. Everything else with symfony I dream to do, works like charm this far... something symfony & database is against me, so I can't do stuff with this

Comment: Check your code into github and we can take a look.

Comment: I made github http://tinyurl.com/z27gygp - battle against symfony logic. It was working all the time, atleast I think so. It does not show database queries performed until you enter correct login details. Thought now when I login with correct login details I get access denied ... its all in this same github repo :)

Comment: Progress at least.  Add hide_user_not_found:  false under security:.  That will narrow it down to user not found or invalid password.  Or just stick a die statement in your load user method.  And I'm not seeing the code where you actually added a user.  Make sure the password has been properly encoded.

Comment: By the way, consider adding var and vendor to gitignore.  No need to check all that stuff in.  The standard installation come with a .gitignore to work from.

Comment: password I added manually to the database from example to test, its hashed already

Comment: now tho, I can't get back to it, I'm not sure what I have done if anything, I just get invalid credentials even if they should be correct

Answer (score 1):

If you check [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#multiple-firewalls-don-t-share-the-same-security-context) on multiple firewalls, you will see the following:

> If you're using multiple firewalls and you authenticate against one firewall, you will not be authenticated against any other firewalls automatically. Different firewalls are like different security systems. To do this you have to explicitly specify the same Firewall Context for different firewalls. But usually for most applications, having one main firewall is enough.

What is actually happening, you are in `login_firewall` and trying to login into `main`, which should actually never work.

What helped me was this:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: database
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
```

See the difference? I removed the whole `login_firewall` section and added `anonymous: ~` into `main` firewall section.

Now, if you configure your `access_control` section right, anything, but `/login`, should not be accessible anonymously:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```